# Seeking point statistic tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, point, spatial-statistics, calculate-values

Does anyone know if there's a tool in QGIS that is equivalent to ArcGIS Point Statistics?

I need to create a raster with values from an attribute in a Point layer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample for the same at https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/spatial_statistics.html

7.4.7. basic Follow Along: Spatial Interpolation
Let’s say you have a collection of sample points from which you would like to extrapolate data. For example, you might have access to the random_samples dataset we created earlier, and would like to have some idea of what the terrain looks like.

To start, launch the Grid (Interpolation) tool by clicking on the Raster ‣ Analysis ‣ Grid (Interpolation) menu item.

In the Input file field, select random_samples.
Check the Z Field box, and select the field srtm_41_19.
Set the Output file location to exercise_data/spatial_statistics/interpolation.tif.
Check the Algorithm box and select Inverse distance to a power.
Set the Power to 5.0 and the Smoothing to 2.0. Leave the other values as-is.
Check the Load into canvas when finished box and click OK.
When it’s done, click OK on the dialog that says Process completed, click OK on the dialog showing feedback information (if it has appeared), and click Close on the Grid (Interpolation) dialog.

As you can see, 100 sample points aren’t really enough to get a detailed impression of the terrain. It gives a very general idea, but it can be misleading as well. For example, in the image above, it is not clear that there is a high, unbroken mountain running from east to west; rather, the image seems to show a valley, with high peaks to the west. Just using visual inspection, we can see that the sample dataset is not representative of the terrain.